# sass automatically inserts white space between and after '/'

Tags: sass

sass automatically inserts white space between and after '/'
in aspect ratio media query :

```
$asrStr: $asrStr + "(min-aspect-ratio:#{$maxAR1}/#{$maxAR2})";
```

I am getting the result:

```
(min-aspect-ratio: 99 / 100)
```

instead of

```
(min-aspect-ratio: 99/100)
```

How to remove these extra white spaces?

Comment: Why should you care? I mean, both results are equal. BTW, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: my media queries are not working, do not understand why, i though maybe because of the space `9 / 10` insted of `9/10`. Anyway, it is annoying why sass automatically isnerts space around `\`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the spaces matter. The following works for me:

```scss
$maxAR1: 99;
$maxAR2: 100;
$asrStr: "(min-aspect-ratio:#{$maxAR1}/#{$maxAR2})";

@media #{$asrStr} {
  div {
    color: red;
  }
}
```